# How to count number of clicks on a button?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem, how to get a number of clicks on a button in jQuery?

I am familiar with javascript code, so any help would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a variable outside of the function scope so it doesn't get reset each time the function is called.

```js
var counter = 0;

function add()
{
  counter++;
  console.log("Button has been clicked", counter, "times(s)");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let clicks = 0;
button.addEventListener('click', () => clicks++);
```